# How to remove a certain annotation pin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation

I've got an application that adds annotation points to a mapView like so:

```
annot = [[AnnotationDelegate alloc] init];
annot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long);
annot.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",id];
annot.subtitle = string;
[mapView addAnnotation: annot];
```

This block of code can be executed several times, as I allow the user to add as many pins as they'd like to the mapView.  My question is, would there be a way to modify this so that the user could REMOVE a certain pin?  Right now I can only seem to remove the one most recently added.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the annotation using

```
[mapView removeAnnotation:annotationToRemove]
```

Presumably you have some form of UI to enable the user to choose which one they are dealing with? For example you could have a scenario where they tap a pin to select it, and then tap a delete button elsewhere in your UI to remove that pin? You could track which one was last selected using something a bit like this;

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    // Do other stuff
    annotationToRemove = view.annotation;    
 }
```

You can also implement the `didDeselectAnnotaionView` method as well.

As always, there's [copious documentation over at Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)